# Initialized Variable Length Array Working Variably (Between Computers)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, gcc, variable-length-array

I have some code that initializes arrays, specifically C-strings, using variables. For example...

```
int len = getLength();
char cstr[len+1] = {'\0'};
```

This compiles and runs flawlessly in my code. However, when one of my co-workers runs the same code, he gets the compiler error...

> Variable-sized object may not be initialized

We're both using Ubuntu and GCC/G++. We've compared compiler flags, and we're both using `--std=c++11`. All the rest of the flags are also the same (`-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-g`).

Why is this code only working on my computer, and not his? How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of **different compiler versions**. When we both ran `g++ --version` in our terminals, we found he was running `4.8`, while I was running `4.9`.

GCC has long supported `C99` variable-length arrays (VLAs), where a variable is declared, but not given an initialization list. Thus, my co-worker could resolve the errors by removing `{'\0');` from each initialization (which also broke the code in this case.)

However, in bygone days, GCC has *not* supported `C++1y` VLAs, which is what I had in the example in the question. They just added support for those in GCC 4.9 (see the [Changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html)).

Ubuntu 14.04 (what my co-worker has) ships with GCC 4.8, while Ubuntu 15.04 (what I have) ships with GCC 4.9. Thus, we had to get onto the same compiler version, namely GCC 4.9. (Instructions for doing that are on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/466651/23786).)

If you're running into this issue on Windows, there are options there as well. As of writing, [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) currently offers GCC 5.2 by default, and [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) offers GCC 5.1.

Comment: @SergeyA: Building a knowledge base is a declared goal of Stackoverflow. The entire scoring system is just a side effect.

Comment: @SergeyA: What do you mean *if* this is promoted? It is being promoted, and it's nothing new. Stackoverflow has yet to turn into Facebook, and some great answers here are self answers. So what's the problem?

Comment: I will add here that I only shared the information because this isn't well documented (since it's so obvious to more experienced programmers), so until one learns about compiler versions having this effect, it's a complete mystery to them. Now Google will yield the answer rather quickly. StackOverfow ranks higher than blogs in search results, so it is better for everyone for it to be posted here.

Comment: @SergeyA: Well, I would not have known the exact answer. And both the question and the answer are well-researched, backed up with references and written in a readable and understandable way. It seems to me like quite a picture-perfect example of a good self answer. I think it is unfair to reduce the answer to "some gcc flavor support VLA, and some do not" or to "different flavors of Ubuntu ship with different compilers". The answer is much more comprehensive than that.