# Why does my C++ compiler accept Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) if the feature is not standard?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, variable-length-array

As we already know, [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (standardized in *C99*) are not part of the standard in C++, so the code below is *"illegal"* in *C++*:

```
void foo(int n) {
  int vla[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    vla[i] = i;
  }
}
```

Despite of that the compiler (*g++* and *clang++*) *accepts* the code as valid syntax, producing just a *warning* in case `-pedantic` flag is enabled.

> ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘vla’ [-Wvla]

My questions are:

- Why does the compiler accept that declaration? 
  Can't the compiler just reject an array in which length `[is-no-know-at-compile-time]`? 
  Is there a sort of compatibility syntax rule to follow?
- What does the standard say about this? 
  From the assembly code produced, I see the compiler writes in the stack
  in the loop, like a normal array, but I cannot find anything about the standard behaviour.

Comment: You have asked two questions, not one.

Comment: Compiler extensions are just that. Extensions.

Comment: "producing just a warning in case `-pedantic` flag is enable." - which is all `-pedantic` promises. `-pedantic-errors` makes these errors instead.

Comment: "the compiler (g++ and clang++) accepts the code" - only in their default modes (which permit extensions) if you enable strict C++ conformance mode (which I'd recommend) the code is *not* accepted. For C++20, use `-std=c++20` (the default is `-std=gnu++20`) and `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why does the compiler accept that declaration?

Because its authors chose to make it do so.

GCC in particular allows, by default, a lot of non-standard stuff that was historically accepted by old C compilers. They like "compatibility" in that sense.

> What does the standard say about this?

The C++ grammar contains the following rule for array declarations in [[dcl.array]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array):

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>      `D1` `[` *constant-expression*<sub>opt</sub> `]` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub>
>
> [...] the type of the *declarator-id* in `D` is "*derived-declarator-type-list* array of `N` `T`"

In simple terms, this means that only a constant expression can be used to specify the size of an array. In your example, `n` is not a constant expression.

**C++ does not have VLAs.**

Where you see one being accepted, it is a compiler extension; to find out how that compiler implements such an extension, you would have to ask the compiler's authors (or examine its source, if applicable).

Comment: "Forbid" is a bit strong. In general, the standard does not forbid extensions. As long as an implementation correctly handles correctly formed programs and issues *required* diagnostics, it is a compliant implementation. If the implementation also provides reproducible behaviour for cetain ill-formed programs, it is still just as compliant; the standard does not care about ill-formed programs.

Comment: @rici Tell that to the GCC devs! _"the standard does not care about ill-formed programs"_ It does! It just doesn't mandate that they fail translation. This "extensions are allowed" all stems from that leniency.

Comment: In what way does my statement differ from the behaviour of gcc? I think the leniency is entirely appropriate; it allows compilers to implement and test proposed additions to the language, something which both gcc and clang devs do. (And how does the standard express its concern about ill-formed programs? It suffices with labelling them as ill-formed and explicitly not defining their behaviour.)

Comment: _"And how does the standard express its concern about ill-formed programs? It suffices with labelling them as ill-formed and explicitly not defining their behaviour."_ Yes, that is how it manifests its concern. If it did not care, it would not even mention them.

Comment: You're right, I should file a bug :-) wrt concern, if I say "I couldn't give a rat's a.. about X, he can do what he bloody well wants", would you the argue that "rici doesn't care about X" is incorrect simply because I bothered to name him? Some shrinks might agree, I guess...

Comment: On top of allowing VLAs in GCC, they actually *just* extended the functionality (as I [discovered recently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33571722/472647)).

Comment: An easy way to get GCC to adhere more closely to the standard and not allow most extensions is to pass (for example) `-std=c++17` rather than just using the default of `-std=gnu++17` (default language version of course changes with compiler version, but the point is, use `-std=c++...` rather than relying on the default or explicitly passing `-std=gnu++...` which enables language extensions). The same goes for the clang compiler btw.

Answer (score 5):

The standard requires that a conforming compiler must "issue a diagnostic" when it encounters something that is illegal. Having done that, it's free to continue to compile the code with an implementation-specific meaning. (Note that "with an implementation-specific meaning" is a polite form of "with undefined behavior").

Comment: @nobar -- the standard does not say what the code does, and it does not require the implementation to document what it does. That's "undefined behavior". Exactly.

Comment: If there is UB and the compiler decides to document precisely what code it emits in that case, it effectively turns into implementation defined behavior on that platform: You can safely use it on this platform, but the code won't be portable to other platforms anymore. Just like you had relied on `sizeof(int) == 4`.