# Expression must have a constant value error in an array with the size input by user

Tags: c++, arrays

So i have this code, part of a larger function.

```
int size, j;
    cout << "Enter the size of array" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    float b, n[size];// error
```

and I get the already famous E0028-expression must have a constant value. Now I saw people getting around this with "new int" and while I kinda understand the concept of it, technically I have not learned this type of int, not yet,nor objects etc. Also where I'm learning c++ they tell me that this should work just fine. I use visual studio enterprise 2017 to code(maybe there is a problem on my end with the compiler). Basically what I want is an array that has the size of it decided by the user input. And yes I know it wants to have a const and not a variable value. What are any work-arounds this ? (answer like you would try to teach your dog programming please because that is where my knowledge lies). Thank you.

Edit: While I see people trying to tell me use std::vector(that again i technically did not learn but kinda understand the concept of it) the people from the place where i'm learning c++ are telling me it should work that way.I did read a bit about the error before asking the question and saw some related stuff about the c99 standard( 2 much stuff to make a wall of text here). So the follow up question is: are they teaching outdated ways of writing this stuff ?
Thank you.

Comment: Didn't the other places where you looked mention `std::vector`? Every time this question gets asked there are at least 3 comments mentioning it.

Comment: Related: [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334435/335858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable length arrays, such as `n[size]`, are not supported by standard C++, although some compilers allow it as an extension. (Note that C allows it, although it was made optional in C11.)

Use `std::vector<float> n(size);` in your case instead. That will allow you to access elements of `n` using `[]`; e.g. `n[0]` is the first element.

As a rule of thumb, use a `std::vector` to model an array of a numeric type, unless you can think of a good reason not to.

Comment: note that it's not allowed in all C standards. C99 requires it but in C11 it's optional

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Too right - that's one for the pub quiz.

Answer (score 0):

The error is selfeplanatory: you cannnot use non-const expression in `float n[size];`.

In your case you need to use `new` operator or use one of standard containers: [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you want to change the array size later on.

Comment: Well thank you for the answer but what i'm actually trying to figure out is why are they telling me it should work ?  On another forum someone suggested it has something to do with the c99 standard(read a bit about it). Is the place where i'm learning just using very old methods that are outdated ?

Comment: @Bubu, C allows it. Some C++ compilers allow it, but as an extension to the language.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you dude, so basically they are using C methods and I should first make sure I understand vectors v well before going to arrays. Or get extensions (which I feel like is kind of cheating in this example) instead of learning new things (vectors) and applying them.

Comment: @Bubu: Indeed. `std::vector` is the way to go.