# How to set array size with const member variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, constant-expression

I tried to set array size with const member variable like below

```
class A {
  const int SIZE;

  A() : SIZE(10) {}
  void aaa() { int a[SIZE]; }
};
```

I cannot build

> a[SIZE]

like this expression.

When I use GCC, build success. But when I use VC++ (Windows), I cannot build.

The error message is "'this' cannot be used in a constant expression"

How to set array size with const member variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers

Comment: C++ need to know array sizes at compile time. Consider making your array size into a template parameter instead of a class member.

Comment: SIZE variable is const variable but member variable.
I already check to build with this expression in gcc. However only Visual C++ compiler cannot build with this expression.

Comment: Can you initialize the constant on the line `const int SIZE = 10;` ?

Comment: `SIZE` is not a constant expression (it is just a const qualified int). If you’re using newer c++ standard versions, you can declare it to be constexpr instead of const and initialize it inline (`constexpr int SIZE = 10;`).

Comment: Or use `static const int SIZE = 10;`

Comment: Variable Length Array is a non-standard extension. Both compilers must have switched to turn this feature on/off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Variable Length Arrays**

> when I use VC++ (Windows), I cannot build.

An array `int a[SIZE]` is created on stack with automatic storage duration.
Then this `SIZE` usually must be determined at compile-time in C++.
But your `SIZE` is defined without a value as follows:

```
const int SIZE;
```

Thus compilers can not know it's value at compile-time and would show compilation error.
So your `SIZE` is a dynamic variable.

> When I use GCC, build success.

...But some C++ compilers support VLA (variable length arrays) which is a C99 addition and allows declaring C-style arrays on stack with a dynamic length.
VC++ does not support C99 and VLA, but [GNU compiler supports VLA as an extension even in C90 and C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).
**This is the reason why you can compile the above code by GCC without errors.**

If you add `-pedantic` (`-pedantic-errors`) option to gcc compile command, we can get warnings (errors) for most gcc extensions.
In this case, with this option we should get warning (error) message: `ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'a'`.

---

**How to fix the current error ?**

(1) If you want to use C-style arrays, one way is making `SIZE` a macro as follows. Then compilers can know it's value at compile-time:

```
#define SIZE 10

class A
{
public:
  A() {}
  void aaa() { int a[SIZE]; }
};
```

(2) Defining the value of `SIZE` as a `static const` variable in the class definition, then compilers again can know it's value at compile-time:

```
class A
{
  static constexpr int SIZE = 10;

public:
  A() {}
  void aaa() { int a[SIZE]; }
};
```

(3) C++ provides array functionality by `std::vector` and `std::array` which might make our code more readable, portable and robust.
I expect that `std::array` on stack would be more efficient than `std::vector` in your case, because 10 `int`s need less memory and `std::array` is allocated on stack just only once without causing problems.
This is a solution with `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

class A
{
  static constexpr int SIZE = 10;

public:
  A() {}
  void aaa() { std::array<int, SIZE> a; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `SIZE` is probably not a macro because, here, you initialize it with 10 and have it as a variable. If it was a macro, your expression `int a[SIZE]` would work but you would not need lines 2-4 anyways.

If `SIZE` is, as here, a normal variable (which includes dynamically creating `A` with a size parameter, *although* the input might be from a macro), you should use a vector.

```
#include <vector>

class A {
  const int SIZE;

  A() : SIZE(10) {}
  void aaa() { std::vector<int> a(SIZE); }
};
```

Usage of `a` is now the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older compiler pre c++11, e.g c++03 you can also do `enum {SIZE=10};`

```
class A {
  enum {SIZE=10};

  void aaa() {int a[SIZE];}
};
```