# Does a two-dimensional array need to be defined as a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, reference

I'm working through the C++ Hackerrank modules, and I've come across a problem asking to output certain values in a two-dimensional array. Here is the problem:

> Consider an *n*-element array, `a`, where each index `i` in the array contains a reference to an array of `k` integers (where the value of `k` varies from array to array)...
>   Given `a`, you must answer `q` queries. Each query is in the format `i j`, where `i` denotes an index in array a and `j` denotes an index in the array located at `a[i]`. For each query, find and print the value of element `j` in the array at location `a[i]` on a new line.

I don't want to make this entire question a quote, so here is the link: [Variable Sized Arrays](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem?isFullScreen=true). Basically, there is the first input line with the above-mentioned `n` and `q`. Then there are `n` lines of integers following, with the first integer in each line of input being `k`, and this is the number of integers following `k` itself in the input line. After these `n` lines is one line with two integers `i` and `j`, denoting the array index and element index respectively.

So, the solution is then to create a two-dimensional array that can be filled in with `n` sub-arrays. Here was my code originally:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int k;
        cin >> k;
        int subA[k];

        for(int j=0; j<k; j++)
            cin >> subA[j];

        arr[i] = subA[k];
    }

    for (int x=0; x<q; x++){
        int i, j;
        cin >> i>> j;
        cout << a[i][j] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error said

```
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
         cout << a[i][j] << endl;
```

and I realized that it was probably because an array isn't an integer type (right?). So then after googling, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) question, which just nonchalantly skips over the fact that one seems to need pointers to create two-dimensional arrays. 
So, when a two-dimensional array is created, does it require the use of pointers? If so, would I be right in stating that pointers are required because they aren't really a type like `int` or `char`, but just hold an address whose type doesn't have to be known?

*P.S.* I understand that the first link I provided provides in itself a link to something about vectors. It didn't give any examples and I have no idea what they are, and googling and Stackoverflow-ing hasn't really helped (especially the i/o part), so I just used something familiar to me, and it seems, through this process of googling and Stackoverflow-ing, that vectors are not needed for a solution such as the high-level one I posed above.

Comment: Please work through error messages top to bottom. There should be one before that about `arr` not being declared. [Do not use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers) [variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) in C++. Don't use raw arrays at all. Use `std::vector` instead. And I also recommend to learn from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is too unforgiving to learn unstructured.

Comment: "*each index i in the array contains a reference to an array of k integers*": The way this assignment is phrased, it seems to assume that you are using raw arrays (which you shouldn't in modern C++) and it technically makes no sense since arrays of references are not possible in C++. You should not continue using the source of this assignment to learn C++.