# Variable-sized object may not be initialized problem in array

Tags: c++, c++11

When I try to run this simple code, it returns a Variable-sized object may not be initialized error. I have no idea why and how to resolve this problem.

```
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    n=1;
    int a[n]={}, b[n]={};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable length arrays are a non-standard compiler extension.  You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead or make `n` `const`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array lenght must be known at compile time.
Either

`int a[1];`

or

```
constexpr int n = 1;
int a[n];
```

Otherwise you need a dynamic array like the std container std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your array properly with the [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) like:

```cpp
std::fill_n(a, n, 0);
std::fill_n(b, n, 0);
```

or use `std::vector` like:

```cpp
std::vector<int> a(n);
```

It will initialize all the elements to 0 by default.

Or, you can have something like:

```cpp
constexpr size_t n = 10;
int a[n]{};
```

This will also initialize all the elements to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const int n=1;

int main()
{
    int a[n]={}, b[n]={};
    return 0;
}
```

The above code will let you create an array with length n.
Note: n can't be changed.