# C++ array[size] greater than 65535 throwing inconsistent overflow

Tags: c++, arrays

Building a struct array with size [x>65535] throws `0xC00000FD error`, even if x is declared as `int64_t`, but inconsistently. Will work fine in one line, not in the next.

```
int64_t length;
length = (pull from other code);
Foo foo[length];
//^ this works
Foo2 foo2[length];
//^ this one doesn't
```

Is this a problem with array construction? C++ max? Compiler/memory limit?

Comment: Are `foo` and `foo2` allocated on heap (global or static) or stack (non-static local)? In latter case, it may be stack overflow.

Comment: Ah, they should be allocated on stack because `static` is not used and they shouldn't be global because variable-length array is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [c++ - Segmentation fault on large array sizes - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes) (I cannot vote because I first voted as debugging detail required)

Comment: VLAs aren't in C++. Also stack has a limit which you might want to change or just use the heap like most people

Comment: Read about `malloc` or `new` in C++. It is the right way for variable array of structures.

Comment: You should use `std::vector<Foo> foo(length);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem 1

[VLA (Variable Length Arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers) aren't in standard C++. This means the following is **illegal** (even if it works):

```
int length;
cin >> length;
int array[length];
```

#### Problem 2

What is `0xC00000FD` error code? It means stack overflow exception. That means you exceeded the stack limit set by your *operating system*. Since you are [on windows, your stack limit by default is **1 MB**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-stack-size).

#### How to fix?

Use the heap.

```
int* myArray = new int[length];
//or even better
std::vector<int> myArray;
myArray.reserve(length);
```

Comment: No VLA, got it.
`Foo myArray = new Foo[length];`
breaks, `error: conversion from 'Foo*' to non-scalar type 'Foo' requested`

Trying the vector solution...

Comment: It should be `Foo* myArray = new Foo[length];`

Comment: Got `vector<Foo> foo(input);` to work nicely. Is there an advantage of one method over the other?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to deallocate memory for vector. for the other you have to `delete[] myArray` to deallocate the memory. Use `vector`, highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You will blow the stack, as you only have a small stack (I think the default is at around 1MB) and VLA arrays are allocated on the stack. (65535*sizeof(int)==~256kb) 256 kb is not the whole stack, but if you allocate another one, you are at 512kb. That's around the half of the stack. Add call frames and other locals and you will pass the size soon ==> Stackoverflow

Comment: I set linker settings in Code::Blocks to '-Wl,--stack,268435456', shouldn't that get around the issue?

Comment: Could be possible