# error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)

Tags: c++14

I am not able to find the solution for the error **no match for 'operator <<'**

below is my code where the error is producing,

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        long int i,n,count=0,idx,min=LONG_MAX;
        cin >> n;
        long int s[n];
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> s[i];
            if(s[i] <= min) {
                min = s[i];
                idx = i;
            }
        }
        
        cout << "count= " << count << " max= " << max << " idx= " << idx << "\n";
    }
}
```

I am getting an error like,

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: prog.cpp:19:43: error: no match
for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and
‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)
      cout<< "count= "<< count << " max= " << max << " idx= " << idx <<"\n";
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

can anyone pls help me to resolve this.

Comment: I don't see a definition of `max`?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [no, please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). `using namespace std;` -- [no, please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). `long int s[n];` -- [no, please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers).

Comment: @DevSolar There is no One True Way to do programming. "I care about future users of this code and I want it to be maximally correct and clear" is one way. "I want this piece of code pass the online judge as fast as possible and I don't care about correctness or clarity" is another way. Neither is inherently better than the other. Who am I to judge a person who works hard towards removing himself from the pool of employable individuals? :)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: If a question be tagged C++, then yea, thou shalt expect the example code they giveth to be conforming to thee standard, which has been carved unto the stones on the mountain of the committee, and thou shalt smite those who cometh and strive to give bad example, or thou shalt see the day when the next generation should grow up and follow the false idols of "competitive programming" in thy office, befouling thy code base so there will be much gnashing of teeth cometh the day of code review... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all max(line 19) is undeclared.
it's giving this error because it is trying to call std::max which is inbuilt(algorithm header file).

i guess you have typo it's min(on line 19) instead of max :).

Comment: Good catch on a case where the combination of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` was actually the culprit! *Nice!* (And no, it's not "inbuilt", this is a result of the very bad practice of dragging in all / most of the standard library in one go.)