# Statically vs Dinamically allocated array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

My textbook states that "The advantage of dynamic allocation is that it is not necessary to know the size of the array at compile time." And they give this example:

```cpp
cout << "how many entries?";
cin >> numEntries;
double * dPtr = new double[numEntries];

cout << "Enter your values.\n";
for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
    cin >> dPtr[i];
}
```

However I rewrote this code with static allocation and it works exactly the same way AFAIK:

```cpp
int numEntries;
cout << "How many entries? ";
cin >> numEntries;
double arr[numEntries];
    
cout << "Enter your values.\n";
for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
}
```

So, what were they trying to say?

EDIT: I'm using gcc version 8.1.0

Comment: It only works on your compiler that implements non-standard C++ extensions. Try it on another compiler and see it fail. or try to allocate an array like that with about ten or so million values and watch your program crash.

Comment: [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334435)

Comment: Although in standard C++ compilers it is not possible to have static array with dynamic size, it is still possible to emulate same behaviour using [alloca()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) function which allocates memory on stack. It is non-standard function, different compilers have different headers/names for it (`alloca()` for GCC, `_malloca()` for MSVC, etc). I made example of usage [here by this link](https://cutt.ly/ukoecgF). Also notice that you DON'T need to call free() on alloca-pointer, stack is freed automatically. Also stack is not too large, limit array size.