# What's the best way to fill multiDimensional Array

Tags: c++, variable-length-array

I am trying to find the best way to fill 2D Array with a specific value.
Is there any better way to loop the 2D Array?
I tried memset doesn't work I tried std::fill but I doubt there is something wrong with my code.

```
void fillMultipleArray(int m, int n, int value)
{
    int grid[m][n];
    
    memset(grid, 0, sizeof(grid));
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            
            std::cout << grid[m][n] << std::endl;
        }
    }    
}
```

Output

> -272632896
> -272632896
> -272632896
> -272632896
> -272632896
> -272632896
> -272632896
> -272632896

Thanks in advance

Comment: @M.A haven't tested, but are you sure that doesn't just set the first one as 666 and the rest of the elements as 0?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 yep good catch :)

Comment: Don't fix the code in your question, it invalidates the posted answer.

Comment: BTW, `int grid[m][n];` is a [non-standard VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

Answer (score 1):

Using `memset` is fine, instead look **carefully** at your printing code, it has multiple mistakes

```
for (int i = 0; i< m; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++) {
        std::cout<< grid[m][n]<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

That should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        std::cout<< grid[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It's a good lesson, when the output is wrong, it could be because your calculation is wrong, but it could just as easily be that you are printing your results wrong. Try not to make too many assumptions.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)  should be j++

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Yes I've fixed it

Comment: Yea I fixed the code printing but it's still giving the same error also i tried this memset but still having the same problem
    memset(grid, 0, sizeof(int) *m*n);

Comment: Yea it works if tried memset(grid, 0, sizeof(int) *m*n);

Comment: Thanks alot the code has been updated to the working one

Comment: @youssefmyh Do you realise that `int grid[m][n] ;` is not legal C++? In C++ array sizes must be constants, but `m` and `n` are variables.

Comment: @john I am using the c++17 Xcode Mac and I am getting no warning.

Comment: @youssefmyh That's because your compiler accepts invalid C++. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers

Comment: @youssefmyh Presumably this is why `sizeof(grid)` didn't work. That would work with a legal C++ array.