# Why is it possible to declare a C++ Array (on stack) with a size, that isn't const or constexpr?

Tags: c++, arrays, constexpr

Almost all sources on the internet say that an array needs to be declared with a value, that is known at compile time like constexpr variables.
But this code works fine for me:

```cpp
int main(){
  int a;
  std::cin >> a;
  int arr[a];
  //...
}
```

normally you'd exspect an compiler error, would't you?
So I'm confused why this works
(compiled with "g++ -m32 -g -std=c++20 main.cpp -o main" on linux)

Comment: Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) are *not* standard C++ ... but some compilers (notably g++) support them as an extension. I've closed this as a duplicate, though there may be a better target.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers

Comment: If you add the `g++` flags that disable the non-standard extensions, then it won't work and you'll be un-confused.

Comment: By seeing the big number of beginner's questions on SO that uses VLA feature (often without knowing it is invalid C++), I am very frustrated that GCC and Clang do support VLA by default, and it is hard to make them reject the feature (`-pedantic-errors`).