# How do I solve the "array initializer must be an initializer list" error?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I've written a problem for an algorithm problem. I'm new to C++, and I'm getting the following error message when I try to run my code: "array initializer must be an initializer list". Here's the code itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n][2];
    int b[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i][0];a[i][1]=i;
        b[i]=a[i][0];
    }

    sort(a,a+n);

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i][0]<=a[i-1][0]){
            a[i][0]=a[i-1][i]+1;
            b[i]=a[i-1][i]+1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";

}
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error message. I've Googled it and couldn't find anything useful. If someone could explain to me why I'm getting this message and how to solve it, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `std::array` with a sort functor.

Comment: What line is the error reported on? Variable length arrays eg `int a[n][2];` are a compiler extension and may not be available with the compiler you are using.  Have a look here - live - https://godbolt.org/z/vePbT5GMT

Comment: VLAs are not allowed in c++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers which is probably the issue (though the error message seems a bit odd)

Comment: For those wondering, it's the `sort(a,a+n);` line that's triggering the error.  Because how do you know if an `int[2]` is ordered before a different `int[2]`?

Comment: The error message (as I could reproduce it) was from this call to sort: `sort(a,a+n);` It looks like the library function is having a hard time initializing the iterator from pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @discovery the compiler does not know how you want `a` to be sorted.  Neither do we.  If `a` contains `{ {1, 0}, {0, 1} }` is that sorted?  How did you determine that?  It may help to [edit] your question to describe what you wanted that problematic line to do.

Comment: @cigien I don't understand why C++ wouldn't allow such a thing. What alternative do I have?

Comment: The problem is coming from the fact that `int[2]` does not satisfy the [ValueSwappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable) requirement. As noted by others, using `std::array<int, 2>` instead of `int[2]` would solve that problem. Changing the line from `int a[n][2];` to `std:array<int,2> a[n];` gets the program to compile, although it is still nonstandard. (Variable-length arrays are permitted by gcc but are not standard-conforming.)

Comment: Use a `std::vector` if you don't know the size up front (at compile time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cin>>n;
> int a[n][2];
> ```

The size of an array variable must be compile time constant. `n` is not compile time constant. The program is ill-formed.

> What alternative do I have?

If you want a runtime size array, then you must create the array in dynamic storage. Simplest approach is to use `std::vector`. Elements of vector cannot be arrays, but you can use `std::array` as the element type instead. Example:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> a;
```

> ```
> sort(a,a+n);
> ```

`a` is an array of arrays. Elements of tha array are themselves arrays. The arguments decay to be pointers to arrays. Pointer to array does not satisfy the requirement of being "value swappable" that is required by `std::sort`. Iterators to `std::array` are "value swappable", so this issue is solved by using that as the inner array as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an array, the size must be **constant number** or you should use **vector** instead. In addition, compiler says you have to assign your array to 0 with curly brackets like that:

```
int a[5][2]={{0}};
int b[5]={0};
```

Comment: I always wonder why people write `int b[5] = {0};`. This means: initialize the first element with `0`, and default-initialize the rest. Why is the first element so special that it deserves explicit zero initialization?..

Comment: No, assigning array to {0} makes all elements 0

Comment: And what will `int b[5] = {1};` do?

Comment: It assings first element to 1 and others to 0

Comment: And this is why I ask - why is the first element so special that it needs a `0` initializer whereas the rest don't? ;) That is, why not `int b[5] = {};` or `int b[5]{};`?