# C++ Sorting Algorithm Returns in the Quintillions When Given 0

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to write my first sorting algorithm in C++, I'm relatively new to it so this might be an endeavor beyond me but I thought I could handle it. When given the input 0 this code returns numbers such as 701635989630, 6560204700, and 1.8*10^19. This doesn't make sense to me at all, nor the people I have asked IRL.

Edit - @Slava had the best suggestion and with his help I was able to get it to work 4 out of 5 times now, but it still fails on the 5th

```
#include <cinttypes>

uint64_t descendingOrder(uint64_t a)
{
  std::vector<int> digits;
  for( auto tmp = a; tmp; tmp /= 10 ){
    digits.push_back( tmp % 10 );
  }
  
  bool run = true;
  
  //sort the array
  while (run) {
    bool change = false;
    for (unsigned long z = 1; z < std::size(digits); ++z){
      if (digits[z]>digits[z-1]){
        unsigned long temp = digits[z];
        digits[z] = digits[z-1];
        digits[z-1] = temp;
        change = true;
      };
    };
    if (change == false){
      run = false;
    };
  };
  
  int finSort = 0;
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < std::size(digits); i++) {
    finSort *= 10;
    finSort += digits[i];
  }

  return finSort;
}
```

Comment: Please rewrite your code to use a `std::vector` instead of a VLA: [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers)

Comment: `sizeof(array)` gives a number of bytes of the array, not a number of its elements.

Comment: The first half of your function is not sorting anything - rip it out, write a function that just sorts (a `std::vector<int>` as already suggested), and then call it with different hard-coded test vectors. Sorting is hard enough without squashing some extra test setup code into the same function.

Comment: `int arrayLength = sizeof(array);` is very interesting solution, especially that you have array size in `n` already.

Comment: The maximum number of digits in a 64 bit integer is... something you can determine before the code runs.

Comment: @TimRandall actually OP counts how many decimal digits particular integer has, not maximum for 64 bit in general.

Comment: @Slava my point is that everyone is talking about how to correctly allocate a variable length array in a situation where one is not needed. This is supposedly a question about a sorting algorithm

Comment: @TimRandall then `sizeof(array)` with or without `/sizeof(array[0])` would confuse OP even more. Notice OP tries to calculate array size when he/she has it already.

Comment: @TimRandall this isn't my code so idk if i can figure out the digits before it runs, I'm testing this off of a site (codewars.com)

Comment: @Slava ...whoops, kinda forgot I had the length

Comment: @Useless I think I get what you're trying to say but at the same time I don't get it at all

Comment: Break your code up into smaller functions. Why are you testing the code for converting an integer to an array of digits and back again? That has nothing to do with sorting, doesn't belong in a sort function, and isn't relevant to a question about sorting. It's bad style in any case, and definitely isn't part of the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your sorting problem.

Comment: @Useless is there a way to rearrange an integer? The simplest way I could think to do it was to change the integer into an array, rearrange the array, then turn it back into an integer

Comment: One thing I forgot to add with the most recent edit is that it doesn't sort it at all, simply spits back out the same thing

Comment: @Botje just read the VLA ask you sent and that was very helpful, albeit not the complete answer for whatever reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C++ Sorting Algorithm Returns in the Quintillions When Given 0

Sorting algorithms sort things. They don't, as a rule, return integers.

```
uint64_t descendingOrder(uint64_t a)
```

This is a function that does three things:

1. convert an integer into an array of digits
2. sort the array of digits
3. convert the sorted array of digits back into an integer

That's two things too many, and only one of them is really relevant to the question. It's clearly *not* a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because the bug is in your sorting code, not in your integer-digit-array-conversion code.

Let's rewrite the function so it isn't trying to do too many things:

```
uint64_t descendingOrder(uint64_t a)
{
    auto digits = integer_to_digits(a);
    bubble_sort(digits);
    return digits_to_integer(digits);
}
```

You already have working code for `integer_to_digits` and `digits_to_integer` so I'm not going to write them out - and anyway, they don't belong in your question in the first place.

Now, we can write the minimal code needed to demonstrate the problem, starting with your existing sorting code:

```
void bubble_sort(std::vector<int> &digits)
{
  bool run = true;
  
  while (run) {
    bool change = false;
    for (unsigned long z = 1; z < digits.size(); ++z){
      if (digits[z]>digits[z-1]){
        unsigned long temp = digits[z];
        digits[z] = digits[z-1];
        digits[z-1] = temp;
        change = true;
      }
    }
    if (change == false){
      run = false;
    }
  }
}
```

and a trivial test harness so we can see it working:

```
void test_bubble_sort(std::vector<int> &digits)
{
    std::cout << "{";
    std::copy(digits.begin(), digits.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << "} -> {";
    bubble_sort(digits);
    std::copy(digits.begin(), digits.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> empty;
    test_bubble_sort(empty);
    
    std::vector<int> zero{0};
    test_bubble_sort(zero);
    
    std::vector<int> one{1};
    test_bubble_sort(one);
    
    std::vector<int> inc{1, 2, 3};
    test_bubble_sort(inc);
    
    std::vector<int> dec{3, 2, 1};
    test_bubble_sort(dec);
}
```

... and the sort itself seems to be fine.

If you have a problem in reality with the `integer_to_digits` or `digits_to_integer`, write another test for *those*, and if necessary ask a question specific to them. Neither the test harness nor the question will have any bubble sorting in them, because these problems are completely unrelated.

When you have a working, tested bubble sort *and* working, tested integer-digit-array conversion, *then* you can combine them into a program that does two things.

Comment: thank you very much, this was quite helpful, https://www.codewars.com/kata/5467e4d82edf8bbf40000155/train/cpp is the question I'm working on that I didn't make so it wasn't really up to me to decide if it would be to an integer or not but the way you split it up and worded it was super easy to understand. Only issue is I'm almost certain it's an issue with my sort since with the 5th test it just doesn't sort even with the exact same style of input. The input is 19 digits if that's an issue

Answer (score 0):

`int arrayLength = sizeof(array);` is ***not*** what you think. It ***does not*** return the size of `array`, but rather how much bytes that `array` comsume.

Also, `int array[n]` is ***not*** valid C++, because arrays' sizes in C++ has to be known in *compile time*. If you want to create an array which sizes are known at runtime, consider using `std::vector`. You just need to change `int array[n]` to:

```cpp
std::vector<int> array;
array.resize(n);
```

Comment: Why resize? Just pass `n` to ctor.

Comment: Or why pre-allocate at all? The first two `for` loops can be 'merged' into one if we just `array.push_back(a % 10);` in each loop. No need for all sorts of resetting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes that i can spot just by first looking at your code snippet:

**Mistake 1**

In C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So you cannot write code like:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //incorrect
```

Correct way to write this would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //correct
```

For the same reason the following code is incorrect in your code as well:

```
int array[n]; //incorrect because n is not a constant expression
```

**Mistake 2**

You're calculating the size of the array incorrectly. The correct would be to use `std::size` with C++17 or use the formula

```
int arrayLength = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);//will work with all C++ versions
```

or with C++17:

```
int arrayLength = std::size(array); //works in C++17 and higher
```

You can/should instead use a variable size container like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the following two changes to the code:

```
int array[20]; // a 64 bit integer won't have more than 20 digits
int arrayLength = n; // we just calculated this
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use proper tool - `std::vector` in this case, your code would be simplified and easier to write and read, as `std::vector` can grow dynamically:

```
uint64_t descendingOrder(uint64_t a)
{
     std::vector<int> digits;
     for( auto tmp = a; tmp; tmp /= 10 )
          digits.push_back( tmp % 10 );
     // your sorting code is here
}
```

Now you have your number digits  in vector `digits`, your array size in `digits.size()` and you do not need 2 loops. Though digits in vector would be in reverse order but it does not matter in your case as you need to sort it.

Comment: I like this code, but I don't understand it enough to implement it sadly

Comment: Note that, with this merged loop, the `a` value is no longer used afterwards, so you don't need to save it or use a `tmp` variable. Once the loop is done, all digits have been pushed into the vector. Also, the elements should really be the same type as the argument, or there should be a `static_cast` in there.