# C++ Compiler successfully compiled a program that initializes a variable-sized object. Why?

Tags: c++

The following code works fine on my C++ compiler despite the fact that it initializes a variable-sized object.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n; std::cin>>n;
    int numbers[n]={1,2,3};
}
```

I'm using g++ 11.2.0 on Ubuntu 21.10.
My IDE issues the warning *Variable-sized object may not be initialized*, but the code still seems to work fine. Why?

Comment: GCC supports it as a non-standard language extension. Use the `-pedantic-errors` flag to make g++ refuse to compiler code using such extensions.

Comment: @πάντα The linked duplicate doesn't really explain why it _does_ work with g++. OP seems to be aware that VLA is not standard C++.

Comment: So try this as a duplicate instead [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers)